# C# Tracking mouse position in FPS game (x/y limitation) at the end of the screen

Tags: c#, position, mouse

I'm tracking vertical mouse movement, subtracting the previous position from the current position. I am using

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

mouse_event(0x0001, 0, 4, 0, 0)
```

to move the mouse down 4 pixels. Everything works fine until the mouse reaches position 1440 (the height of my display). I test the program in an FPS game using

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out PointInter lpPoint);
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PointInter
{
    public int X, Y;
    public static explicit operator Point(PointInter point) => new Point(point.X, point.Y);
}
public static Point GetCursorPosition()
{
    GetCursorPos(out var lpPoint);
    return (Point)lpPoint;
}
```

and I get the following values:

```
1423
1427
1431
1435
1439
1439
1439
1439
```

I can't find a working option that will allow me to either reset the mouse position to 0, or somehow get around this limitation, because it's impossible to track the number of pixels. I tried the NeatInput library, it sometimes shows values ​​1441, 1442, 1443, but no more, and if i move mouse by 10 pix down the values ​​are still not correct. I tried to find something like absolute mouse shift but couldn't find. Can anyone please help me with the solution?

Comment: Welcome to SO! More details are nice. What framework/library/game engine are you using to track mouse position and render stuff?

Comment: Thanks, in any FPS game, it doesn't matter, the mouse cannot go below 1440. Any library/code for C# .Net 4.8 will work for me. It is a shooting assistant that is trained by the user. Everything works fine until the mouse reaches 1440.

Comment: Is this just a case of starting at 0 not 1? 1 to 1440 vs 0 to 1439

Comment: No, if you look at the list of pixels, you will see that the mouse moves down 4 pixels. And at the end of the list, can you figure out how far down the mouse is? 1439 is no different from 1439, that's the problem, it's just the fact of movement. I have to track the movement of the mouse. Let's say I know that the mouse only moves 4 down, but I have no idea how much it moves down if the user pulls the mouse down.

Comment: no ideas, guys?